# CF Moto Glory will not crank

Tags: starting

My scooter will not turn over. The battery is good and the starter is good. The starter spins. It all spins the gear it slides into. And that gear spins the bigger gear which I assume should be turning the engine. But the  engine doesnt turn over[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you put a socket onto the large nut ( the one inside what appears to be the basket for the clutches - lower right of the picture)? If so, can you turn it a bit and inspect the teeth on the larger ring gear? If you cannot turn it, then you know you have bigger issues. I'm wondering if teeth are stripped from either the intermediate (reduction) gear (on the inside) or the larger ring gear which attaches to the engine. If there's damage, you should be able to see something on the large ring gear without taking the entire thing apart.